# Required attribute to custom radio button in html

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I am using Custom Radio Button. Also added required attribute to it.

Required is working but ERROR not shown....

Form not get submitted without selecting radio....

**But**

> "Please Select One of These Options"

**error is not shown**.

code is :

```
<form>
 <div class="form-field-label">Change In Weight :</div>
             <div class="form-field-input">

  <input type="radio" name="change_in_weight" id="change_in_weight1" required value="Maintained" class='radiobutton'><label for="change_in_weight1"  class='radiobutton-label'>Maintained</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="change_in_weight" id="change_in_weight2" value="Increasing abnormally since last one year" class='radiobutton'><label for="change_in_weight2" class='radiobutton-label'>Increasing abnormally since last one year</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="change_in_weight" id="change_in_weight3" value="Decreasing abnormally since last one year" class='radiobutton'><label for="change_in_weight3"  class='radiobutton-label'>Decreasing abnormally since last one year</label><br>
              </div>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

CSS :

```
.radiobutton-label {  
  display: inline-block;  
  cursor: pointer;  
  position: relative;  
  padding-left: 25px;  
  margin-right: 15px;  
  font-size: 15px;  
}  

input[type="radio"] {
 display:none;
 margin: 10px;
}

.radiobutton-label:before {  
  content:"";
  display: inline-block;  
  width: 24px;      
  height: 24px;  
  margin-right: 10px;  
  position: absolute;  
  left: 0;  
  bottom: 1px;
}  
input[type=radio] + label:before {  
  background: url('http://drdilipgadgil.com/img/vlad.png') 2px 4px no-repeat;
}  

input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {  
  background: url('http://drdilipgadgil.com/img/vlad.png') 2px -18px no-repeat;
}
:required:focus {
  box-shadow: 0  0 6px rgba(255,0,0,1); 
}
```

Here is **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vaidyamanishjoshi/2du3s/665/)**

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm late But since I had the same problem and I've looked it up and stumbeled on this thread, I would like to say that THERE IS A WAY.

1- don't hide your actual radio button (DON'T set `display :hidden;`

2- set it's opactity to 0 and position to absolute

---

----it worked fine for me

```
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
```

---

[Here is JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sqctvzL0/)

Comment: yes! and width and height to 100%, margin to 0, z-index to -1 and container to relative

Answer (score 1):

In the case of custom radio buttons, you have to handle error cases separately. Error is not showing because radio buttons are hidden. If you give 'display:block' for radio buttons, you can see the error after submitting. So you can go for two solutions.

Keep default radio buttons

OR

Handle error case via JS, and show custom message.

Answer (score -1):

Just try to make some function in javascript when the button is clicked and the radio button is empty (nothing selected) just display the error in any div or whatever you want. (for example just use alert to simply test it)